# Are all SATA cables compatible with SATA 3?

Tags: sata, compatibility

I have a HP Compaq de5700 Small Form Factor desktop computer, and I am looking to upgrade it's hard drive.  When I open up the box, it clearly has available SATA connectors on the motherboard, but no indication as to which SATA version (1, 2, or 3).  The hard drive I am considering is a  SATA 3.  My concern is that if the motherboard also supports SATA 3 and I use an old SATA cable (v1 or v2), might there be problems?  This is a bare drive, so I don't expect that a cable will come with it, and I have not been able to find the manual for this machine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes. There is no difference in the cables. They have not changed with SATA revisions.

> When the Serial ATA International Organization (SATA-IO) began design of the 
>   SATA Revision 3.0 specification, the designers wanted to double the interface data rate 
>   while enhancing support for multimedia applications − without introducing major 
>   changes that could adversely affect cost, increase design complexity, or reduce the 
>   quality and performance of the SATA interface. Key to meeting this goal is maintaining 
>   backward compatibility with SATA 3Gb/s connectors and cabling.

Source (pdf): http://www.serialata.org/documents/SATA-6-Gbs-The-Path-from-3gbs-to-6gbs.pdf

Answer (score 8):

We were discussing this on chat - I did a little digging and both [maximum PC](https://web.archive.org/web/20150423045626/http://www.maximumpc.com:80/article/features/your_sata_cable_slowing_down_your_data_transfers_max_pc_investigates) and [puget systems](http://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/SATA-cables-Is-there-a-difference-97) did benchmarks on various cables.

Maximum PC had a more interesting variety of cables and found they worked identically, even when used beyond the specified distance. Puget system tried it with a typical set of cables and found there's little difference.

Empirically, if its a to spec, non damaged cable, it should work fine even with sata 3. Modern cables are probably made to higher tolerances and should work alright. I'd go with 'sata 3' cables if I had them but for most purposes, It looks like it dosen't matter.

Comment: +1 I miss hanging out in chat!!! Very interesting and I didn't realise...  I think I will still continue to use the SATA 3 cable "as it is there" in the box (and, it would look better if people look in their machines!), but nice to know it actually technically doesn't matter.

Answer (score -1):

The compatibility is not a question, they look the same and work the same as you can read in the other replies. I think the main question is whether there are speed differences between the cables.

I found 2 tests:

- sata 2 vs sata 3 cables: https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/SATA-3Gb-s-vs-6Gb-s-Cable-Performance-Revisited-183/
- sata 1 vs sata 3 cables: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjtIKOSVpto

Apparently the sata 1 cable can support at least 3.2Gbps and the sata 2 cable can support at least 4.0Gbps. Maybe by faster speeds there is a difference, but I somehow doubt that too, since you cannot change much in these cables. If you have a quality cable I don't think there is any difference regarding to speeds or anything else.