# How to switch from SATA 2 to SATA 3 after cloning HDD to SSD

Tags: windows-10, ssd, sata, disk-cloning, switching

I have recently cloned my old HDD of my laptop to a new Kingston HyperX Savage. But it only shows half the speeds it should get. I followed the tips from this thread:

[How can I determine the SATA controller version on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/633839/how-can-i-determine-the-sata-controller-version-on-windows?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

and found out that the SSD is currently running in SATA 2 mode but both my motherboard controller and the disk, of course, supports SATA 3. Can I just switch modes? Or how do fix this issue? Reinstall Windows 10 (I upgraded from Windows 8.1 which in turn was upgraded from Win7)?

Comment: Note that most boards have more than one IO controller so some ports may be sata 3Gb/s and others may be Sata 6Gb/s. Consult your motherboard manual to confirm which sata ports you should connect to.

Comment: Perhaps providing the exact model of your motherboard will help in identifying the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually far simpler than reinstalling Windows and such.

Connect the Kingston HyperX Savage to a SATA3 connector on your motherboard. Refer to its instruction manual to find out which one is SATA3. (It may have a mix of SATA2 and SATA3 connectors.)

Comment: there's [no difference](https://superuser.com/a/412158/685512) between SATA3 cables and SATA2 cables.  the motherboard connectors could differ -- some controllers only provide SATA3 on specific ports.